# How to get list items inside <ul> which is inside a <li> of another <ul> to stack horizontally?

Tags: html, css

This has been driving me nuts! I can get one group of list item's to **stack horizontally** (by floating) inside of a un-ordered list by limiting the height of the un-ordered list.

However, if I put a un-ordered list inside of one of the list items (that is inside the original list), then they cease to stack horizontally... I've tried everything.. what'd going on here? Why doesn't that work???

They should be like this:

█ █ █ █

Not like this:

█ 
█ 
█ 
█

Here is an example:

```
<style>
.container {
    width:auto;
    height:34px;
    float:left;
}
.container ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    float:left;
    height:34px;
}
.container li {
    width:34px;
    height:34px;
    float:left;
}
.container ul li ul {
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    height:34px;
}
.container ul li ul li {
    width:34px;
    height:34px;
    float:left;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test2</li>
                <li>test3</li>
                <li>test3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It's probably something stupid I'm overlooking I'm sure...

A working example: http://jsfiddle.net/csdigitaldesign/cugF5/

Comment: could you post the scenario that doesn't work?

Comment: This exact scenario in the example... try it. I've even added separate (although unneeded because it cascades) styles to the sub <ul> and <li>s.

Comment: sorry, misread question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly due to the cascading nature of CSS. The container for your floated list elements is not wide enough. Why?

Without a nested list, your elements float fine. This is because the `ul` containing the items and the `div` containing the items have the full width (since they are block elements).

However, when you have the nested list, your floated list elements are now contained by the `div` (which is fine), the two `ul`s (which is fine), but **also the outer li**. Note that the outer `li` has also been set to have a width of `34px`, which is not wide enough to contain the floated elements horizontally.

To fix this issue, you will have to make sure the outer li element does not get the `34px` of width. One possible solution is to place the `34px` of width only in the inner `li`:

```
<style>
.container {
    width:auto;
    height:34px;
}
.container ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:34px;
    float: left;
}
.container li {
    height:34px;
    float:left;
}
.container ul li ul li {
    width:34px;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test2</li>
                <li>test3</li>
                <li>test3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note that unless you are trying to float the container too, you shouldn't need the `float: left` on the div.

jsfiddle demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/AvwRw/2/

Answer (score 1):

try list-style:none;

```
.container li {
width:34px;
height:34px;
float:left;
list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: No that doesn't help at all. Besides it was already set in the <ul>

Comment: oh sorry, totally oversawn: try a .container li ul li { and then set the css propertys

Comment: That is unneeded because it already cascades down into the sub items... however I added it anyways in the example even though its redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You have to watch the width, the items are all floating left, but the width of the inner <ul> is not enough to hold them in a row horizontally.

Try adding this:

```
width:400px;
```

to

```
.container ul
```

Then you'll see the items stack horizontally.

-Ken

Comment: Is there no way to set the width automatically? it works when it's just ONE set of <ul> and <li>s.. why not when there is another inside an element?

Answer (score 1):

restart and make nothing float, exept your `<li>` second level.
http://jsfiddle.net/cugF5/1/

```
.container {
    width:auto;
    height:34px;
    background:red;
}
.container ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background:green;

    height:34px;
}
.container li li {
    width:34px;
    height:34px;
    background:purple;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
}
.container ul li ul {
    list-style:none;

    height:34px;
}
.container ul li ul li {
    width:34px;
    height:34px;
    background:purple;

    list-style:none;
}
```

Just like this , the example might not help you so much if you think of building a menu with 2 or more levels :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.. yes you can add a forced width to the unordered list inside the list item that will work but its a fixed width.

The real problem that I wasn't wrapping my head around that fact the unordered list was inside the container of the parent list item... and that list item was set to 34px.  Setting the first parent list item to auto fixed the issue... (just keep in mind that list item will be just as wide as its contents).

*I was in the middle of typing this when Compid mentioned the same thing... but he/she pointed it out just before I did.. so I will give them the credit.*

Answer (score 0):

Format your lists specifically for that list. A container is a separate thing. This is good coding practice. Float the li not the ul. You have no formatting for the nested list. You can create a separate style eg"ul2" for that and see what looks good to you.

```
.ul1{                    
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:34px;
}
.ul1 li {
    width:34px;
    height:34px;
    float:left;
}
</style>

<ul class = "ul1">
<li>
<ul class ="ul2">
<li>test</li>
<li>test2</li>
<li>test3</li>
<li>test3</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yea I need to avoid assigning a class to the <ul>... its for a joomla template menu. The PHP generates the code on the fly and inserts a style-less <ul> for me.. so I target it in other ways.